# ERROR "The accessTokenId cannot be null". how to config google calendar connector? Mule ESB

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule, google-calendar-api, mule-studio, connector

Im trying to use Calendars Connector, i have this configuration.

```
   <google-calendars:config-with-oauth 
    name="Google_Calendars" 
    consumerKey="myKey" 
    consumerSecret="mySecretKey" 
    doc:name="Google Calendars" 
    applicationName="Football Organizer">

    <google-calendars:oauth-callback-config 
        domain="localhost" localPort="8081" remotePort="8081" />
    </google-calendars:config-with-oauth>
```

Then i have this flow, just to try adding a quick event

```
<flow name="calendarFlow1" doc:name="calendarFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
     host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <google-calendars:quick-add-event 
      config-ref="Google_Calendars" 
      calendarId="myCalendarPublicID@group.calendar.google.com"  
      doc:name="Google Calendars" text="Im a quick event!"/>
</flow>
```

When i send a request it throuws "Failed to invoke quickAddEvent. Message payload is of type: String"

Trace:

```
ERROR 2014-08-07 15:57:49,730 [[calendar].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke quickAddEvent. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. The accessTokenId cannot be null (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  org.mule.module.google.calendar.oauth.ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor:46 (null)
2. Failed to invoke quickAddEvent. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.google.calendar.processors.QuickAddEventMessageProcessor:153 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The accessTokenId cannot be null
    at org.mule.module.google.calendar.oauth.ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.mule.module.google.calendar.oauth.ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedAccessTokenProcessInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.mule.module.google.calendar.oauth.ManagedAccessTokenProcessTemplate.execute(ManagedAccessTokenProcessTemplate.java:32)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you authenticate with OAuth2 against the `oauth-callback` endpoint first?

Comment: I did. But the problem remains. http://prntscr.com/4amhlq

Comment: Is there any way to skip authorization, and set a defaultAccessTokenID?

Comment: No, you need to go through the OAuth2 authentication process. Also typically the authorize endpoint is in a different flow than the flows where calendar actions are used.